# How do I embed ads in .NET Compact Framework application?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, compact-framework, ads

I'm writing a C# [.NET Compact Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework) application and would like to embed ads into it (e.g. small banner on top of every screen). However, I couldn't find any advertising SDKs. Aren't there really any?

If implementing it from scratch, how would you do it? Google's Ad Sense for example only works with mobile websites (that can be reached by Google's bot).

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile ad networks are focused on iPhone apps, but the only one I could see that supports Windows Mobile is [SOMA](http://www.smaato.com/soma) by a company called Smaato.

Comment: thank you, but I cannot find an API on their website. Is it still in development and not open to public yet?

Comment: I don't know, but you could send them an email to ask?

Answer (score 0):

[Amobee](http://www.amobee.com/main/developers.htm) has a advertisement SDK that can return a banner of predefined size to an application.
They offer a JAVA Api, but getting an ad from their service is as easy as accessing a URL with some query-string and downloading a image.